# InnerText alternative in mozilla

Tags: javascript, innertext

Does any one know innerText alternative of a span in mozilla? 
My span is

```
<span id='cell1'></span>
```

and the javascript is

```
document.getElementById('cell1').innerText = 'Tenelol';
```

But Mozilla is not supporting this!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a proprietary IE thing. The [W3C defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent) [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) as the official property.

An easy way is to exploit the `||` logical operator and its [short circuiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation) nature, as well as JavaScript returning the last evaluated value in a condition (most times the *truthy* operand).

```
var body = document.body,
    text = body.textContent || body.innerText;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/8LAyA/).

(Note in the fiddle I checked for the `innerText` first. This was only because most people on here do not use IE. IRL, check for `textContent` first, and fallback to `innerText`.)

Comment: And since `textContent` is not supported by IE you'll have to use both.

Comment: for more reference http://help.dottoro.com/ljermebq.php

Comment: @Parusa The fiddle may not be clear enough, I'll place the code inline :)

Comment: `textContent` and `innerText` can give you different results so it's not recommended to use both of them in or.
http://www.kellegous.com/j/2013/02/27/innertext-vs-textcontent/

Comment: @Yuri It depends on what you're going to do with it. In some cases, further massaging may be required.