# innerText alternative in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, innertext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [InnerText alternative in mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015388/innertext-alternative-in-mozilla)

I have this code

```
<div id="code">My program<br />It is here!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var program=document.getElementById('code');
ShowLMCButton(program.innerText);
</script>
```

It works in IE but in firefox, innerText does not work. How can I use this in firefox? I have tried .text() but it doesn't want to work! I need the text to be in the form "My program\n It is here!" It can't be textContent because that copies the html tags.

What this is, is to copy a VB script from a site and paste it straight into a program and it must include all the new lines, white space etc.

ShowLMCButton() is a script that is "Click to Copy" - http://www.lettersmarket.com/view_blog/a-3-copy_to_clipboard_lmcbutton.html

Comment: what is `ShowLMCButton`?

Comment: If you are using jQuery you can try `ShowLMCButton($(program).text());`

Comment: Updated my question @DanielA.White and $(program).text() doesn't work because it doesn't include the new lines

Answer (score 3):

use textContent for firefox

```
ShowLMCButton(program.innerText || program.textContent)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery to do this:

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/WS7G3/)**

```
ShowLMCButton($('#code').text());
```

Comment: It copies the text, it just doesn't copy the returns and the white space like innerText does

Comment: @josh it gives spaces as well. http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/WS7G3/

Comment: It does, but I want the contents to be copied to the clipboard using the LMCButton script and then pasted into notepad with the new lines too, which your answer does not do

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/WS7G3/1/ Try it in firefox and paste into notepad and then in IE and paste into notepad. See the difference?