# Javascript get the value from an h4 Tag

Tags: javascript

i am trying to get the value **Lotus** of the **h4** tag from the code below

```
    <a id="linkSale" class="linkAccess" title="" href="/vp4/Home/Handlers/OperationAccess.ashx?operationid=17285" onclick="javascript:PrepareEventOnLinksAnchor(17285);">

    <h4>Lotus</h4>

    <p class="dateSales">Du <em><strong>mercredi&nbsp;1 mai</strong>&nbsp;9h</em> au <em><strong>dimanche&nbsp;5 mai</strong>&nbsp;6h</em> </p>

    <p class="baseline"></p>

    </a>
```

to do that i did as follow :

`var h=document.getElementById("17285");`

`var i=h.getElementsByTagName("h4");`

which returned the following line :

```
<h4>Lotus</h4>
```

what I want is to get the value `Lotus` converted to a text.

Comment: did you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321739/how-can-i-get-the-text-only-no-tags-from-a-html-document

Comment: BTW: id's must not be numbers only, they have to start with a character at least

Comment: Numbers are allowed in html5

Answer (score 2):

Any of these will work - I recommend the last

```js
console.log(
  document.getElementById("linkSale").getElementsByTagName("h4")[0].textContent,
  document.getElementById("linkSale").querySelector("h4").textContent,
  document.querySelector("#linkSale h4").textContent
)
```

```html
<a id="linkSale" class="linkAccess" title="" href="/vp4/Home/Handlers/OperationAccess.ashx?operationid=17285">
  <h4>Lotus</h4>
  <p class="dateSales">Du <em><strong>mercredi&nbsp;1 mai</strong>&nbsp;9h</em> au <em><strong>dimanche&nbsp;5 mai</strong>&nbsp;6h</em> </p>
  <p class="baseline"></p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

**you can use jQuery for that :**

```
<h4 id="title">Lotus</h4>
```

**to include script on top:**

```
<script>[[jQuery .js File Path]]</script>
```

**On document ready do like this:**

```
$(document).ready(){ 
     var text=$('#title').html();
});
```

**but I would recommend to use id.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for that :

```
<h4 id="title">Lotus</h4>
```

to include script on top:

```
<script>[[jQuery .js File Path]]</script>
```

On document ready do like this:

```
$(document).ready(){ 
     var text=$('#title').html();
});
```

but I would recommend to use `id's` or `classes`

Comment: I just wanted to cover it all :) maybe he has it in a form..anyway text() should do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use "innerHTML" in your example.

```
 var text = h.getElementsByTagName("h4")[0].innerHTML;
```

Or "innerText"

```
var text = h.getElementsByTagName("h4")[0].innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this type of work. With jQuery, it's pretty easy:

```
var i = $('h4').text();
```

However, whenever you can - use the id attribute.

```
<h4 id="doc_head">Lotus</h4>
```

Then in JS:

```
var i = $('#doc_head').text();
```

If you don't want to use jQuery for some reason - get the text like that (ugly):

```
var i = h.textContent || h.innerText; // having your DOM object in h
```

The above should work in both IE and W3C compliant browsers, look here - [InnerText alternative in mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015388/innertext-alternative-in-mozilla)